# unable to install gnome

Tags: gnome, server, dependencies

Hey! I have ubuntu server 10.10. I am trying to install gui. I have installed these packages: xserver-xorg xinit

I tried installing gnome but I always get this error:

> The following packages have unmet
>   dependencies:  gnome : Depends:
>   gnome-desktop-environment (>=
>   1:2.28+1ubuntu4) but it is not going
>   to be installed
>            Depends: epiphany-extensions but it is not going to be installed

I can't seem to find the epiphany-extensions.
This is my source.list file:

> deb
>   http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   maverick main restricted deb-src
>   http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   maverick main restricted
>
> deb
>   http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   maverick-updates main restricted
>   deb-src
>   http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   maverick-updates main restricted
>
> deb
>   http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   maverick universe deb-src
>   http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   maverick universe deb
>   http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   maverick-updates universe deb-src
>   http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   maverick-updates universe
>
> deb
>   http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   maverick multiverse deb-src
>   http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   maverick multiverse deb
>   http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   maverick-updates multiverse deb-src
>   http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   maverick-updates multiverse
>
> deb
>   http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   maverick-backports main restricted
>   universe multiverse deb-src
>   http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   maverick-backports main restricted
>   universe multiverse
>
> deb
>   http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu
>   maverick partner deb-src
>   http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu
>   maverick partner
>
> deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   maverick main deb-src
>   http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   maverick main
>
> deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   maverick-security main restricted
>   deb-src
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   maverick-security main restricted deb
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   maverick-security universe deb-src
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   maverick-security universe deb
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   maverick-security multiverse deb-src
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   maverick-security multiverse

What can I do to correct this? How can I find a source url that has the package I need??

Answer (score 5):

If you what you want is basic GNOME, you probably should try:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment --no-install-recommends
```

IF you want a desktop just like you would have if you installed the Desktop Edition, try:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I just want a basic desktop just to see it there really are any advantages in having gui in the server edition. Thanks I'll try this :) But do you know where I can find the missing package??

Comment: Gnome is so deeply rooted in the Ubuntu desktop, its hard to get it without all the extra bits because of all the tight integration. You might also check out 'xubuntu-desktop' which includes xfce and some of the lighter weight, more traditional linux apps. Ultimately though, a GUI just wastes valuable RAM that a server can use for other things.

Answer (score 0):

If the instructions by Leon Nardella does not work, you could try to use a different server in sources.list.